# React + Meteor + Bootstrap Modal managing data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, meteor, meteor-1.4

I have a Meteor application with React where I have a component called `ChatManager`.  The component imports my `chatrooms.js` API for publishing my `chatrooms` collection. It also imports my `EditChatRoom` component and my `ChatRoomRecord` component.

Basically here is a summary of the file structure of relevant code:

```
-imports
  -api
    -chatrooms.js
  -ui
    -chatmanager
      -ChatRoomRecord.jsx
      -EditChatRoom.jsx
    ChatManager.jsx
```

My `ChatRoomRecord` component has an `onClick` function which works successfully at logging the click and the `chatroom` prop.

My `EditChatRoom` is a `modal` where `id="editChatRoomModal"`

The `ChatManager` component is the one that holds both the `ChatRoomRecord` and the `EditChatRoom` components.

How can I send that `chatroom` prop that I've registered through to the `EditChatRoom` component? And on a side note, how could I open the `editChatRoomModal` using React?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:** *Added Information*

Here is a basic representation of my `ChatManager` Component:

```
class ChatManager extends Component {
    renderChatRoomRecords() {
        return this.props.chatrooms.map((chatroom) => (
            <ChatRoomRecord key={chatrooom._id} chatroom={chatroom} />
        ))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <EditChatRoom />
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.renderChatRoomRecords()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ChatManager.PropTypes = {
    chatrooms: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('chatrooms')
    return { chatrooms: ChatRooms.find({}).fetch() }
}, ChatManager)
```

Then here is my `ChatRoomRecord` component:

```
export class ChatRoomRecord extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("Click registered successfully: " + this.props.chatroom._id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr onClick{this.handleClick}>
                {/* This code isn't relevant to the problem */}
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

ChatRoomRecord.PropTypes = {
    chatroom: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

This works greats so there's no problem in the mapping and the click event works where it registers the click and shows the `chatroom._id` that was clicked.

Here's my `EditChatRoom` component:

```
export class EditChatRoom extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal fade" id="editChatRoomModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
                {/* This code isn't relevant to the problem */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I need to open this modal and pass through the `chatroom` that was clicked in my `ChatRoomRecord` component.

Hope this better explains the problem.

Comment: can you  just store it as a session variable? Then grab it with Session.get(). Otherwise, redux.

Comment: Oooooh, yeah that's a good idea, didn't think about that.  That helps with the data side of things, now I'll need to figure out what to do regarding opening the modal.

Comment: This has given me the idea to try manage it using the URL parameters. So I'll try to use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `Session` to show the selected record and the state of the modal (show or hide):

ChatRoomRecord.jsx

```
export class ChatRoomRecord extends Component {
    // ...

    handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        Session.set('selectedRecordId', this.props.chatroom._id);
        Session.set('isShowModal', true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

EditChatRoom.jsx

```
class EditChatRoom extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      selectedRecordId
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="modal fade" id="editChatRoomModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
        {/* use the selectedRecordId */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {

  // show modal if isShowModal is true
  if (Session.get('isShowModal')) {
    $('#editChatRoomModal').show();
  } else {
    $('#editChatRoomModal').hide();
  }

  return {
    selectedRecordId: Session.get('selectedRecordId'),
  };
}, EditChatRoom)
```

This code works though it is just for demonstration how to solve your problem. I recommend you use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) instead of the normal Bootstrap. And use another reactive source ([ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) or [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict)) to store reactive values instead of Session, because Session has global scope so it is very easy to mess up

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate the other advice that came along with that as well :)